# Is there any justification not to ALWAYS use AtomicInteger as data members?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, atomic

In a multi-threaded environment like Android, where a simple `int` variable may be manipulated by multiple threads, are there circumstances in which it is still justified to use an `int` as a data member?

An `int` as a local variable, limited to the scope of the method that has exclusive access to it (and thus start & finish of modifying it is always in the same thread), makes perfect sense performance-wise.

But as a data member, even if wrapped by an accessor, it can run into the well known concurrent interleaved modification problem.

So it looks like to "play it safe" one could just use `AtomicInteger` across the board. But this seems awfully inefficient.

Can you bring an example of thread-safe `int` data member usage?

Comment: What operations on int aren't atomic?  (Honest question, this is a new topic to me.)

Comment: @djechlin Even a `++` isn't atomic.

Comment: `++` isn't atomic, but reads are writes (assignments) are. In other words, you'll never get interleaved bytes. The problem with `++` is it is shorthand for `i = i + 1`, and there maybe a mutation between the read and the assignment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any justification not to ALWAYS use AtomicInteger as data members?

Yes, there are good reasons to *not* always use `AtomicInteger`.  `AtomicInteger` can be at at least an order of magnitude slower (probably more) because of the `volatile` construct than a local `int` and the other `Unsafe` constructs being used to set/get the underlying `int` value.  `volatile` means that you cross a memory barrier *every* time you access an `AtomicInteger` which causes a cache memory flush on the processor in question.

Also, just because you have made all of your fields to be `AtomicInteger` does not protect you against race conditions when multiple fields are being accessed.  There is just no substitute for making good decisions about when to use `volatile`, `synchronized`, and the `Atomic*` classes.

For example, if you had two fields in a class that you wanted to access in a reliable manner in a thread program, then you'd do something like:

```
synchronized (someObject) {
   someObject.count++;
   someObject.total += someObject.count;
}
```

If both of those members with `AtomicInteger` then you'd be accessing `volatile` twice so crossing 2 memory barriers instead of just 1.  Also, the assignments are faster than the `Unsafe` operations inside of `AtomicInteger`.  Also, because of the data race conditions with the two operations (as opposed to the `synchronized` blocks above) you might not get the right values for `total`.

> Can you bring an example of thread-safe int data member usage?

Aside from making it `final`, there is no mechanism for a thread-safe `int` data member except for marking it `volatile` or using `AtomicInteger`.  There is no magic way to paint thread-safety on all of your fields.  If there was then thread programming would be easy.  The challenge is to find the right places to put your `synchronized` blocks.  To find the right fields that should be marked with `volatile`.  To find the proper places to use `AtomicInteger` and friends.

Comment: OK. So how do you guarantee thread-safety of a class with `int` data members?

Comment: You have to properly `synchronize` around the class.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: Yes, but isn't locking the *entire class* even less efficient?

Comment: No because you only are crossing a single memory barrier even if you are accessing multiple fields.  Also, it allows you to take the synchronization performance hit when you need to.  When you know you are updating the object or when you need to ensure you have a consistent synchronized value.

Comment: Volatile isn't the only performance hit associated with AtomicInteger. Ultimately reads and writes resolve to different and slower processor instructions.

Comment: @Gray +1. I couldn't expect a better answer than that. One more related question since you mentioned the keyword `synchronized`: I could swear that I saw somewhere that using the annotation `@Synchronized` is superior to `synchronized`. Is this true? Can you refer to that in your answer?

Comment: I think `@Synchronized` is for some some 3rd party package @ef2011.  I've never actually heard of it.  Maybe it was introduced in some later version of Java because Java<6 does not support it.

Comment: @Gray Found it: http://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized.html Also found this great overview: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html Many thanks & accepting.

Comment: Using `AtomicInteger` may not help _at all_.  It all critically depends on what exact concurrency invariants you want your class to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

If you have effecitvely immutable `int`s you can get away with not ensuring synchronization at the cost of its calculation.  An example is `hashCode`

```
int hash = 0;

public int hashCode(){
   if(hash == 0){
     hash = calculateHashCode(); //needs to always be the same for each Object
   }
   return hash;
}
```

The obvious tradeoff here is the possibility of multiple calculations for the same hash value, but if the alternative is a `synchronized` hashCode that can have far worse implications.

This is technically thread-safe though redundant.

Comment: ...this isn't threadsafe?  Thread 1 does hash == 0, thread 2 does hash == 0, 1 calculates and returns, 2 calculates and returns.  Different values coming out of the same hashCode.

Comment: Aside from the duplicate calculations what side effects will you incur?

Comment: hashCode can return different values on different invocations in a threaded environment, this isn't true in a non-threaded environment.

Comment: I made it clear in my answer that the `calculateHashCode` needs to return the same value for each Object

Comment: @djechlin Would you say Java's `String` is not thread-safe? That class does a very similar operation.

Comment: Oh, I see, I was confusing your hashCode with calculateHashCode.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it is used wrt. other data.  A class encapsulates a behavior, so often a variable is almost meaningless without the others.  In such cases it might be better to protect(*) data members that belong together (or the whole object), instead of just one integer.  If you do this, then `AtomicInteger` is an unnecessary performance hit

(*) using the common thread safety mechanisms: mutex, semaphore, monitor etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety is not only about atomic int assignments, you need to carefully design your locking patterns to get consistency in your code.

If you have two `Account` classes with a public datamembers `Balance` consider the following simple code.

```
Account a;
...
int withdrawal = 100;
if(a.Balance >= withdrawal)
{
    // No atomic operations in the world can save you from another thread
    // withdrawing some balance here
    a.Balance -= withdrawal
}
else
{
   // Handle error
}
```

To be really frank. In real life, having atomic assignments is rarely enough to solve my real life concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Google saw the OP and updated their documentation on the subject to be clearer:

"An AtomicInteger is used in applications such as atomically incremented counters, and cannot be used as a replacement for an Integer."

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger