# When is AtomicInteger preferrable over synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, atomic

Since `AtomicInteger` can be at at least an order of magnitude slower than an `int` protected by `synchronized`, why would I ever want to use AtomicInteger?

For example, if all I want is to increment an `int` value in a thread-safe manner, why not [always](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851273) use:

```
synchronized(threadsafeint) {
  threadsafeint++;
}
```

instead of using the much slower [AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet%28%29)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Since AtomicInteger can be at at least an order of magnitude slower than an int protected by synchronized, why would I ever want to use AtomicInteger?

AtomicInteger is much faster.

```
static final Object LOCK1 = new Object();
static final Object LOCK2 = new Object();
static int i1 = 0;
static int i2 = 0;
static final AtomicInteger ai1 = new AtomicInteger();
static final AtomicInteger ai2 = new AtomicInteger();

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        testSyncInt();
        testAtomicInt();
    }
}

private static void testSyncInt() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int runs = 10000000;
    for(int i=0;i< runs;i+=2) {
        synchronized (LOCK1) {
            i1++;
        }
        synchronized (LOCK2) {
            i2++;
        }
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("sync + incr: Each increment took an average of %.1f ns%n", (double) time/runs);
}

private static void testAtomicInt() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int runs = 10000000;
    for(int i=0;i< runs;i+=2) {
        ai1.incrementAndGet();
        ai2.incrementAndGet();
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of %.1f ns%n", (double) time/runs);
}
```

prints

```
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 32.4 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 20.6 ns
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 31.4 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 12.9 ns
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 29.6 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 12.9 ns
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 35.1 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 16.6 ns
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 29.9 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 13.0 ns
```

---

Adding some contention as @assylias suggests. It shows that when you are only really using one thread the CPU can optimise the access.

```
static final Object LOCK1 = new Object();
static final Object LOCK2 = new Object();
static int i1 = 0;
static int i2 = 0;
static final AtomicInteger ai1 = new AtomicInteger();
static final AtomicInteger ai2 = new AtomicInteger();

public static void main(String... args) throws  ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        testSyncInt();
        testAtomicInt();
    }
}

private static void testSyncInt() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    final int runs = 1000000;
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int t=0;t<8;t++) {
        futures.add(es.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < runs; i += 2) {
                    synchronized (LOCK1) {
                        i1++;
                    }
                    synchronized (LOCK2) {
                        i2++;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }));
    }
    for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
        future.get();
    }
    es.shutdown();
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("sync + incr: Each increment took an average of %.1f ns%n", (double) time/runs/2);
}

private static void testAtomicInt() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    final int runs = 1000000;
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int t=0;t<8;t++) {
        futures.add(es.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < runs; i += 2) {
                    ai1.incrementAndGet();
                    ai2.incrementAndGet();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }));
    }
    for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
        future.get();
    }
    es.shutdown();
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of %.1f ns%n", (double) time/runs/2);
}
```

prints

```
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 478.6 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 191.5 ns
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 437.5 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 169.8 ns
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 408.1 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 180.8 ns
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 511.5 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 313.4 ns
sync + incr: Each increment took an average of 441.6 ns
incrementAndGet: Each increment took an average of 219.7 ns
```

Comment: I'm now really confused. That's not what I understood from @Gray's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11125474/722603 What am I missing?

Comment: I think he means that `AtomicInteger` is slower than an *unsynchronized* `int`; he's talking about why you shouldn't replace all your `int` members with `AtomicInteger` without justification.  But it's not an order of magnitude slower, any more than it's an order of magnitude faster. For the most part these are all small differences we're talking about.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that locking mechanism also different for Atomic stuff, but couldn't get that reference right now. I may be wrong too.

Comment: @thinksteep - Atomic types typically don't use locking.  They use atomic "compare and swap" instructions, and the like.  Reference: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11234/

Comment: @StephenC: Thanks for the link it will refresh my understanding.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You have been gentle - you could have added a little bit of contention to make the case of the CAS vs. monitor ;-)

Comment: Wow. If so, the answer is simple: When you need that extra performance *and* `AtomicInteger` can still satisfy thread safety requirements (although this could be tricky sometimes in regard to race conditions). Did I get this right this time?

Comment: @assylias It slowed down the updates significantly, but the relative result was the same.

Comment: @ef2011 I would agree that AtomicInteger is the best choice if it does exactly what you need. If you have other operations you need, it might not be.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Interesting - I would have thought differently. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Checking JCiP 15.3.2 - the effect seems more noticeable with moderate contention but it can reverse at high contention levels.

Comment: At 8 threads on 8 cores, the performance is the same.  If this is all your program does, you need a redesign IMHO. ;)

Answer (score 2):

if you really want to get more details on why `java.util.concurrent` stuff is better and what the difference is compared to the classical synchronized approach, read [this link](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/11/biased-locking-osr-and-benchmarking-fun.html) (and the whole blog generally)